# Validate that each comma separated value exists in database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.4, my users have an auto-complete helper to put values into an input. I want to validate that each of the values exists in the database when inserting.

Inputted value for "unit" : "12,13,14"

How do I check that, unit "12" and unit "13" and unit "14" exist in the database before doing the insert?

```
$units = array_filter(array_unique(explode(",", $request->unit))); 
 // input "12,13,14" becomes [12,13,14]

$this->validate($request,[
        'unit'  => 'required|exists:units.id,'.$units,
]);
```

Do I have to use a custom validation rule, or does laravel have something handy like 'required|existsAllValuesInThisArray' sorta thing? Haven't found anything in documentation about it.

---

I also found this, but it's for like multiple select fields or checkboxes sorta thing from the looks of it.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

---

Update : I ended up using javascript to split the input into an array before sending it off for processing. So my input name became "units[]" instead of "units"

Comment: I think you have 2 possible ways: modify your input in js and send to the server an array, validated with the second snippet posted by you and using a custom validation rule

Comment: Try  `$this->validate($request,[
        'unit.*'  => 'required|exists:units.id,'.$units,
]);`. Since `$units` is an array, the rule `unit.*` should check for each element of the array.

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata , your answer is correct. Can you post it?

Comment: @Darius I just did, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$this->validate($request,[ 'unit.*' => 'required|exists:units.id,'.$units, ]);
```

Since `$units` is an array, the rule `unit.*` should check for each element of the array.

Comment: is $units in this example not an array then as otherwise we get an array to string conversion error?

Comment: @SamBremner, probably should use `'unit' => 'array'` as well